# Text and symbols get capped in math mode

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, arrays, sharelatex

I use these the following setup in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[oribibl]{llncs}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{todonotes}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
```

The following code does not display correctly:

```
\[  
    a^x = \left\{  
    \begin{array}{l l}  
        a^{x/2} * a^{x/2} & \quad \text{if $x$ is even}\\  
        a * a^{x-1}       & \quad \text{if $x$ is odd}  
    \end{array} \right.
\]
```

It becomes:

[image]

I had a similar problem with `\mathbb{Z}`, where wrapping the 'Z', like so `\mathbb{\text{Z}}`, makes it look right. This, however, does not seem to work for the first problem with the curly brace.

[image: Z displayed correctly and Z being capped off]

What am I missing? And how to fix the first problem?

Comment: The two questions have a different scope. Just ask another question for your second problem, and edit that part out of this question of course.

Comment: (1) why don't you use `cases` instead of `\left\{` + `array`. (2) Exactly how are you previewing this? You tagged with `sharelatex` are you viewing in the browser or downlowading the result and viwing in say Adobe Reader?

Comment: @Ruben, not knowing the source of the error, I expected them to be related. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: @andershqst, the clipping seems related to me, thus my question above

Comment: @daleif, I just downloaded it, it displays correctly in Adobe Reader!

Comment: Ok, so it seems to be an issue with the build in pdfviewer in your browser. BTW: looking at where you are from you might want ot have a look in my Danish LaTeX book: http://math.au.dk/videnudveksling/latex/bog/

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a problem with the way sharelatex displays the pdf. I'm using Chrome, which displays the text correctly if I simply open the pdf in Chrome. Thanks for sharing your book!

Answer (score 4):

For your situation the AMS bundle provides the `cases` environment:

```
\[  
    a^x =  
    \begin{cases}  
        a^{x/2} * a^{x/2} & \text{if $x$ is even,}\\  
        a * a^{x-1}       & \text{if $x$ is odd.}  
    \end{cases}
\]
```

This should avoid your clipping errors in the output.

Answer (score 1):

For situations where `\left...\right` don't work, an alternative is the `\scaleleftright` macro from the `scalerel` package.

```
\[  
    a^x = \scaleleftright[1.5ex]{\{}{  
    \begin{array}{l l}  
        a^{x/2} * a^{x/2} & \quad \text{if $x$ is even}\\  
        a * a^{x-1}       & \quad \text{if $x$ is odd}  
    \end{array}}{.}
\]
```